# SQL WHERE Input field

Tags: php, html, sql

```
 <input type="text" name="lastn" style="width:20%;" placeholder="Nachname" >
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suchen"class="login-button">

       $lastn = $_POST['lastn'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Security_BNB` WHERE lastn='". $lastn. "'";
```

How do I get it to have the entry from the input field behind WHERE lastn =?

Comment: You need to put your input tags in [a form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

Comment: I have it, but it don't want to work

Comment: Thats not an explanation we can assist with, it's too vague. Edit the question to show your updated code and explain more specifically what goes wrong when you try to run it. If you can't give a more detailed explanation yet, do some debugging.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how this code works - between the client and server, and passing information between them.  That's why a form has been suggested, so the data can be posted back to the server, and you can access the form data, and inject it into the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information bit hard to help, but is your form method set to post as the default is get

`<form method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure what you are asking, But from what I can gather, the solution to your question is:

```
<form action="path/To/PHP/File.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="lastn" style="width:20%;" placeholder="Nachname" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suchen"class="login-button">
</form>
```

File.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $lastn = $_POST['lastn'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Security_BNB` WHERE lastn='". $lastn. "'";
}

?>
```